# Return get set method value to label

Tags: c#, winforms

In my Windows form I have 2 text boxes namely, start odometer reading and end odometer reading. My goal is to subtract the "start reading" from the "end reading" and display the difference in the label next to the Name and phone number of the client in the windows form label.

How do I return the value of the method `getMilesCharge()` and display it on the `confirmLabel`?

Code for the Car Rental Class

```
//A class that represents the Rental Agency Class.
namespace Assignment1
{
  partial class RentalAgencyClass
  {
    //instance variables
    public string customerName { get; set; }
    public string phoneNumber { get; set; }
    public double sMiles { get; set; }
    public double eMiles { get; set; }
    public double noOfDays { get; set; }
    private double DAY_CHARGE = 15;
    private double MILE_CHARGE = 0.12;

    //Constructor class
    //sets the value of the starting and ending miles.
    //sets the value of the number of days the car was rented for
    public RentalAgencyClass(double startMiles, double endMiles, double days)
    {
      startMiles = sMiles;
      endMiles = eMiles;
      days = noOfDays;
    }

    //method to calculate the number of miles driven on the rental
    public double getMileCharge()
    {
      double milesDriven = 0;
      milesDriven = eMiles - sMiles;
      return milesDriven * MILE_CHARGE;
    }

    //method to calculate the Day Charges on the rental
    public double getDayCharge()
    {
      return noOfDays * DAY_CHARGE;
    }

    //Property to display the information on the label
    public string GetInfo()
    {
      return customerName + " | " + phoneNumber + " | " + getDayCharge() +" miles";
    }
  }
}
```

Form Designer Class code

```
namespace Assignment1
{
  public partial class RentalAgencyClass : Form
  {
    RentalAgencyClass aCarRental;

    public RentalAgencyClass()
    {
      InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void calculateButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
      try
      {
        //instantiates object
        aCarRental = new RentalAgencyClass();
        aCarRental.customerName = nameTextBox.Text;
        aCarRental.phoneNumber = phoneTextBox.Text;
        //aCarRental. = getDayCharge();               
        // aCarRental.milesDriven = //store the difference in this variable
        //displayLabel.Text = "(student information saved)";
      }
      catch (Exception err)
      {
        MessageBox.Show(err.Message, "Error");
      }

      //Displays information about the Rental
      confirmLabel.Text = aCarRental.GetInfo();
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: java? javascript? where?

Comment: I was hoping the concept would be the pretty much the same in other languages as well sir, my apologies for the error.

Comment: There isn't a question here.  Are there errors?  Where do you need help?

Comment: I am unable to return the value of the difference from the method to get it displayed on the Windows form label. Would like some guidance.

Comment: I guess start by fixing your constructor.  You have things backwards: `startMiles = sMiles;` should be `sMiles = startMiles;`  I don't see you passing any information when you create that object.  `aCarRental = new RentalAgencyClass();` should be an error.

Comment: Should you just replace `getDayCharge()` with `getMileCharge()` in your `GetInfo()` method? Or are you asking something else? Your problem statement isn't clear.

Answer (score 0):

By calling `aCarRental = new RentalAgencyClass();` within your `calculateButton_Click` method you are calling the parameterless constructor of your `partial class RentalAgencyClass`, which means in your case, you are creating a new instance of your form instead of setting your properties. So `sMiles` and `eMiles` will stay by their default value `0`.

To get your code working you have to do several steps.

At first I recommend you should split your form and your agency class.
So let's say, rename your form class to `RentalCalculator`. As a next step you have to/can remove the `partial` from your `RentalAgencyClass`, because it is not a part of your form class anymore and I assume you did not want to extend your class in another part of your code.

As [LarsTech](https://stackoverflow.com/users/719186/larstech) pointed out in the comments. You should now fix your `RentalAgencyClass` constructor to:

```
public RentalAgencyClass(double startMiles, double endMiles, double days)
{
    this.sMiles = startMiles;
    this.eMiles = endMiles;
    this.noOfDays = days;
}
```

and may add the following property to your class

```
public double milesDriven
{
    get
    { 
        return this.eMiles - this.sMiles;
    }
}
```

At least you have to change your event handler:

```
private void calculateButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    try
    {
        // if not existing you have to create some input textboxes
        double startMiles = Convert.ToDouble(startMilesTextBox.Text);
        double endMiles = Convert.ToDouble(endMilesTextBox.Text);
        double days = Convert.ToDouble(daysTextBox.Text);

        // Hint: you are creating a new instance on every button click 
        //       and overwriting your field in your form class. 
        aCarRental = new RentalAgencyClass(startMiles, endMiles, days);
        aCarRental.customerName = nameTextBox.Text;
        aCarRental.phoneNumber = phoneTextBox.Text;

        // Store the result in local variables
        // if you want to do something with them later
        double dayCharge = aCarRental.getDayCharge();
        double milesCharge = aCarRental.getMilesCharge();               
        double drivenMiles = aCarRental.milesDriven;

        // displayLabel.Text = "(student information saved)";
    }
    catch (Exception err)
    {
        MessageBox.Show(err.Message, "Error");
    }

    //Displays information about the Rental
    confirmLabel.Text = aCarRental.GetInfo();
}
```

---

Answering your question:

> How do I return the value of the method `getMilesCharge()` and display it on the `confirmLabel`?

You will have to change the following line in your `calculateButton_Click` method from:

```
confirmLabel.Text = aCarRental.GetInfo();
```

to:

```
confirmLabel.Text = aCarRental.getMilesCharge().ToString();
```

---

*Last but not least let me give you a kind advice.

You may take a look at the [Microsoft Naming Guidelines](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/design-guidelines/naming-guidelines).

For example: Properties should be named in PascalCasing.

But this is just my personal opinion.*